# Integral of Gaussian ring/shell

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I would like to know the integral of the function

$$f(\mathbf{x}) = {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left\{- {(|\mathbf{x}| - \mu)^2 \over 2\cdot \sigma^2}\right\} $$

over an $n$-dimensional vector space. It is a ring of radius $\mu$ around the origin, where the deviation from the radius yields a fall-off according to a Gaussian with standard deviation $\sigma$.

I had no success with WolframAlpha/Maxima/SymPy, probably due to the norm $|\mathbf{x}|$.

Is the right approach to switch to spherical coordinates, and then integrate along the ring first, and finally over the radius?

The radial function would be:

$$g(R, \phi) = {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left\{- {(R - \mu)^2 \over 2\cdot \sigma^2}\right\} $$
so that
$$\int_0^\infty dR \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi ~~ g(R, \phi) = 2\pi\cdot 1 = 6.28 $$

I do not think this result is correct, for 2d it should be 0.087 according to a paper I have (for 5d 0.0017; using $r=2$, $w=0.1$).

### Update

I missed out to use the volume element dV. In the general integration over the n-sphere (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area)):

$$ d^nV = r^{n-1}\sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-3}(\phi_2)\cdots \sin(\phi_{n-2})\, dr\,d\phi_1 \, d\phi_2\cdots d\phi_{n-1} $$

Now the integral 
$$ \int g(R) R^{n-1} dR $$
is the (n-1)th moment of the gaussian, $M_{n-1} = \operatorname{E}\left[X^{n-1}\right]$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments), and scipy.stats.norm.moment(n-1, loc=r, scale=sigma))

So then we are only missing the rest of the volume elements. This is the "surface area" of a unit n-sphere (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Recurrences) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#The_volume)).
$$ S_{n}={(n+1) V_{n+1}}$$
with 
$$V_n = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}$$

So I should be able to write the complete integral as

$$ I = \int_{\cal{R}^n} g(R, \mathbf{\theta}) dV = S_n \cdot M_{n-1} $$

For n=2: 
The first moment with $\mu=2$, $\sigma=0.1$ is $M_1=2$. The surface $S_2=4\pi$. This gives $I_2 = 25.1$, which is still not what it ought to be.

Comment: In 3D, what are you integrating over? A sphere? Are we essentially integrating over an $n$-ball?

Comment: Integrating over $\cal{R}^n$. A $n$-ball is fine.

Comment: As for your calculation you are missing the Jacobian in the 2D calculation.

Comment: @ChrisK, could you have another look now

Comment: The update seems to assume that $\mu=0$, is this what you want?

Comment: No, that's not what I want, @Did. The mistake is using the (absolute!) central moment instead of the normal Non-central moment. I guess I should be using the $\mathrm{E}\left[X^p\right]$ formula instead, but somehow non-central. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ and $\Phi$ denote the standard normal PDF and CDF, that is,
$$
\varphi(t)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2},\qquad\Phi(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t\varphi=\int_{-t}^\infty\varphi.
$$
Using spherical coordinates as you explained one is led to compute $\displaystyle\int g(R)R^{n-1}\mathrm dR$ the integral in your post, which is
$$
A_n(\mu,\sigma^2)=\int_0^\infty r^{n-1}\varphi\left(\frac{r-\mu}\sigma\right)\mathrm dr/\sigma.
$$
The change of variable $r=\sigma t$ yields
$$
A_n(\mu,\sigma^2)=\sigma^{n-1}B_{n-1}(\mu/\sigma),\qquad B_k(u)=\int_0^\infty t^k\varphi(t-u)\mathrm dt.
$$
Now, for $k=0$,
$$
B_0(u)=\int_{-u}^\infty \varphi=\Phi(u).
$$
Using the fact that $\varphi'(t)=-t\varphi(t)$, one sees that
$$
B_k'(u)=\int_0^\infty t^k(t-u)\varphi(t-u)\mathrm dt=B_{k+1}(u)-uB_k(u).
$$
One deduces from this that there exists some sequences $(P_k)$ and $(Q_k)$ of polynomials such that, for every $k\geqslant0$,
$$
B_k=P_k\varphi+Q_k\Phi.
$$
These are uniquely determined by the initial condition $(P_0,Q_0)=(0,1)$ and by the recursion
$$
P_{k+1}(u)=P'_k(u)+Q_k(u),\qquad Q_{k+1}(u)=Q'_k(u)+uQ_k(u).
$$
For example,
$$
(P_1(u),Q_1(u))=(1,u),\quad (P_2(u),Q_2(u))=(u,1+u^2),\quad (P_3(u),Q_3(u))=(2+u^2,3u+u^3).
$$
One recognizes (or a direct computation shows that), for every $k$,
$$
Q_k(u)=\mathrm i^{-k}H_k(\mathrm iu),
$$
where $H_k$ is the $k$th [Hermite polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

Comment: That is a good start. Now we know something about the momentum-formulae, and can compute them for e.g. n=2, or n=5. Since that seems ok, there must be a problem in the way I mixed in the "surface" of the n-ball?

Comment: Not sure one can go much further than this "good start".

Comment: I also computed the momentum numerically, and it is indeed $A_2=M_1=2$. But if I compute the integral over the Gaussian shell numerically, I get, like in the paper, 0.00691. Something is missing (sorry for the edit-confusion).

Comment: I had a transformation mistake in the numerical computation, and in the way I took over the information from the paper. The computation (multiplying the (n-1)th momentum with the surface of the n-sphere is correct.